ComfyUI Hosting on Replicate Issue: Model Download Failure for LayerMask SegmentAnythingUltra v2
I'm trying to host my ComfyUI workflow on Replicate, and I created my own Python pipeline using Cog. Inside ComfyUI, I'm using a node called LayerMask SegmentAnythingUltra v2. It only supports the models shown in the screenshot below. After creating and pushing the Docker image to Replicate, I encountered an issue while running it.

ComfyUI Node screenshot sam
GroundingDino Model list_screenshot
While loading LayerMask: SegmentAnythingUltraV2, the model is not being downloaded into Replicate from Hugging Face, indicating there's no connectivity for downloading the model. I also tried changing the model name in the weight.json file, but that didn't work.
There was an error executing your workflow: {     "type": "execution_error",     "data": {         "prompt_id": "7606f994-3f69-4a77-a299-d91f1b1c757d",         "node_id": "1",         "node_type": "LayerMask: SegmentAnythingUltra V2",         "executed": [             "187",             "255",             "2",             "268",             "269",             "258",             "257",             "267"         ],         "exception_message": "We couldn't connect to 'https://huggingface.co' to load this file, couldn't find it in the cached files and it looks like bert-base-uncased is not the path to a directory containing a file named config.json.\nCheckout your internet connection or see how to run the library in offline mode at 'https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/installation#offline-mode'.",         "exception_type": "OSError",         "traceback": [             " File \"/src/ComfyUI/execution.py\", line 323, in execute\n output_data, output_ui, has_subgraph = get_output_data(obj, input_data_all, execution_block_cb=execution_block_cb, pre_execute_cb=pre_execute_cb)\n",             " File \"/src/ComfyUI/execution.py\", line 198, in get_output_data\n return_values = _map_node_over_list(obj, input_data_all, obj.FUNCTION, allow_interrupt=True, execution_block_cb=execution_block_cb, pre_execute_cb=pre_execute_cb)\n",             " File \"/src/ComfyUI/execution.py\", line 169, in _map_node_over_list\n process_inputs(input_dict, i)\n",             " File \"/src/ComfyUI/execution.py\", line 158, in process_inputs\n results.append(getattr(obj, func)(**inputs))\n",             " File \"/src/ComfyUI/custom_nodes/ComfyUI_LayerStyle/py/segment_anything_ultra_v2.py\", line 64, in segment_anything_ultra_v2\n DINO_MODEL = load_groundingdino_model(grounding_dino_model)\n",             " File \"/src/ComfyUI/custom_nodes/ComfyUI_LayerStyle/py/segment_anything_func.py\", line 119, in load_groundingdino_model\n dino = local_groundingdino_build_model(dino_model_args)\n",             " File \"/src/ComfyUI/custom_nodes/ComfyUI_LayerStyle/py/local_groundingdino/models/__init__.py\", line 17, in build_model\n model = build_func(args)\n",             " File \"/src/ComfyUI/custom_nodes/ComfyUI_LayerStyle/py/local_groundingdino/models/GroundingDINO/groundingdino.py\", line 362, in build_groundingdino\n model = GroundingDINO(\n",             " File \"/src/ComfyUI/custom_nodes/ComfyUI_LayerStyle/py/local_groundingdino/models/GroundingDINO/groundingdino.py\", line 97, in __init__\n self.tokenizer = get_tokenlizer.get_tokenlizer(text_encoder_type)\n",             " File \"/src/ComfyUI/custom_nodes/ComfyUI_LayerStyle/py/local_groundingdino/util/get_tokenlizer.py\", line 19, in get_tokenlizer\n tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(text_encoder_type)\n",             " File \"/root/.pyenv/versions/3.10.15/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/models/auto/tokenization_auto.py\", line 864, in from_pretrained\n config = AutoConfig.from_pretrained(\n",             " File \"/root/.pyenv/versions/3.10.15/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/models/auto/configuration_auto.py\", line 1006, in from_pretrained\n config_dict, unused_kwargs = PretrainedConfig.get_config_dict(pretrained_model_name_or_path, **kwargs)\n",             " File \"/root/.pyenv/versions/3.10.15/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/configuration_utils.py\", line 567, in get_config_dict\n config_dict, kwargs = cls._get_config_dict(pretrained_model_name_or_path, **kwargs)\n",             " File \"/root/.pyenv/versions/3.10.15/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/configuration_utils.py\", line 626, in _get_config_dict\n resolved_config_file = cached_file(\n",             " File \"/root/.pyenv/versions/3.10.15/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/utils/hub.py\", line 446, in cached_file\n raise EnvironmentError(\n"         ],         "current_inputs": {             "sam_model": [                 "sam_vit_h (2.56GB)"             ],             "grounding_dino_model": [                 "GroundingDINO_SwinT_OGC (694MB)"             ],             "threshold": [                 0.3             ],             "detail_method": [                 "VITMatte"             ],             "detail_erode": [                 35             ],             "detail_dilate": [                 6             ],             "black_point": [                 0.15             ],             "white_point": [                 0.99             ],             "process_detail": [                 true             ],             "prompt": [                 "clothes"             ],             "device": [                 "cuda"             ],             "max_megapixels": [                 2.0             ],             "image": [                 "tensor([[[[1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000],\n [1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000],\n [1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000],\n ...,\n [1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000],\n [1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000],\n [1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000]],\n\n [[1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000],\n [1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000],\n [1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000],\n ...,\n [1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000],\n [1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000],\n [1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000]],\n\n [[1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000],\n [1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000],\n [1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000],\n ...,\n [1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000],\n [1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000],\n [1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000]],\n\n ...,\n\n [[0.8667, 0.8510, 0.9059],\n [0.8667, 0.8510, 0.9059],\n [0.8627, 0.8510, 0.9020],\n ...,\n [0.8392, 0.8235, 0.8745],\n [0.8431, 0.8235, 0.8784],\n [0.8431, 0.8275, 0.8824]],\n\n [[0.8627, 0.8510, 0.9020],\n [0.8627, 0.8510, 0.9020],\n [0.8627, 0.8510, 0.9020],\n ...,\n [0.8431, 0.8275, 0.8745],\n [0.8471, 0.8235, 0.8784],\n [0.8392, 0.8235, 0.8745]],\n\n [[0.8549, 0.8471, 0.8941],\n [0.8588, 0.8510, 0.9059],\n [0.8627, 0.8471, 0.9098],\n ...,\n [0.8431, 0.8275, 0.8784],\n [0.8431, 0.8314, 0.8745],\n [0.8392, 0.8235, 0.8667]]]])"             ]         },         "current_outputs": [             "1",             "54",             "255",             "266",             "256",             "280",             "9",             "202",             "4",             "201",             "177",             "56",             "63",             "7",             "151",             "163",             "166",             "263",             "13",             "180",             "146",             "19",             "171",             "68",             "183",             "197",             "100",             "178",             "52",             "187",             "103",             "173",             "181",             "129",             "259",             "58",             "165",             "269",             "199",             "61",             "44",             "62",             "150",             "46",             "179",             "47",             "65",             "261",             "102",             "184",             "39",             "2",             "268",             "149",             "260",             "69",             "53",             "257",             "66",             "168",             "258",             "267",             "264",             "271",             "167",             "20"         ],         "timestamp": 1727868596646     } }
I tried changing the weight path for the LayerMask model, but that didn’t work. Instead, I think we might just need to enable something to allow connectivity on Replicate, so it can download the default model automatically.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
